# Software (or webapps) for teaching kids statistics or probability?

Tags: probability, references, software, teaching

I would like (in the distant future) to teach statistics to kids.  For that matter, I'd be happy to know of software (obviously I am tending towards FOSS), or webapps, that are helpful in explaining statistical/probabilistic ideas to kids (or adults for that matter).

This can be used either by the instructor, the kids, or both.

<sub>Suggested format of the answer: Software name, what it help teach, who should use it, link.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Videos](http://understandinguncertainty.org/view/videos) and [animations](http://understandinguncertainty.org/view/animations) from Understanding Uncertainty website.

Comment: I didn't know about them, thanks Radek.

Answer (score 7):

**RcmdrPlugin**.TeachingDemos: Rcmdr Teaching Demos Plug-In

Extending R with Rcmdr and give demos for probability and statistics ideas.

- Interactive: correlation and linear regression.
- Static: power of a test, confidence interval, central limit theorem.

Mostly for the teacher - less for the children

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcmdrPlugin.TeachingDemos/index.html

Answer (score 5):

**GGobi**

Help teach interactive data visualization.  Including - histograms, scatter plots (2d, 3d, multi-d), with brushing/linking etc.

Mostly for the teacher - less for the children (but still possible)

http://www.ggobi.org/

Answer (score 4):

**animation**: A Gallery of Animations in Statistics and Utilities to Create Animations

An R package.  Enables the teacher to create many animation that can be made into webapps.

Great for the teacher to create a children webapp.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html

Examples:
http://animation.yihui.name/

Answer (score 0):

The [University of Michigan Statistics Online Computational Resource (SOCR)](http://socr.umich.edu) provides hundreds of Java applets (require Java-enabled browsers) as well as JavaScript-based webapps that run in the browser directly. Some [videos, documentation, learning activities](http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_EduMaterials) are also provided.